# Riak ruby client trying to delete CRDT map

Tags: ruby, riak, crdt

using ruby client (2.3.0) with Riak 2.0. I've created a CRDT bucket type of 'Maps', which store (surprise) maps.

Everything works including search, etc. but for the life of me I can't work out how to delete a map when I no longer need it.

I've tried this based on things I found:

```
robject = @bucket.get @key, type: 'maps'
robject.delete
```

This does not give an error, but the map is not removed from Riak; neither is it 'tombstoned' as I can still retrieve the data from it and the search index still has the data too.

I've also tried:

```
@bucket.delete @key, 'maps'
```

but this doesn't work either. It gives error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" and without 'maps' it doesn't work either.

Looking at the first option in the console, it looks to me it is accessing the correct object, but calling 'delete' on it seems to have no effect.

How do I correctly delete the map? At least if I can have it removed from indexing results would be a big step!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d'oh, didn't read the docs correctly.

it's simply:

```
@bucket.delete @key, type: 'maps'
```

I missed the 'type:'

Silly